# How to run my Python code for every Excel file contained in a folder?

Tags: python, dataframe, directory, iteration, multiple-file-upload

I have a folder named with a certain acronym, and inside this folder you can find a certain number of Excel files.
The folder's name indicates the name of the apartment (for ex. UDC06_45) and, inside this folder, all of the Excel files' name are composed by:
the name of the apartment, followed by the name of the appliance that is located in that apartment (for ex. UDC06_45_Oven).

These Excel files are very simple DataFrames, they contain energy consumption measurements: one column named "timestamps" and one column named "Energy" (all of these measurements have a 15 min frequency). All of the Excel files inside the folder are made with the same identical structure.

My Python code takes as input **only one** of these Excel files at a time and makes few operations on them (resampling, time interpolation, etc.) starting with the command "pd.read_excel()", and creates an output Excel file with "df.to_excel()" after giving it a name.

What I want to do is to apply my code **automatically to all of the files** in that folder.
The code should take as input only the name of the folder ("UDC06_45") and create as many output files as needed.
So if the folder contains only two appliances:

- "UDC06_45_Oven"
- "UDC06_45_Fridge"

the code will elaborate them both, one after the other, and I should obtain two dinstinct Excel files as output. Their name is just composed by the input file's name followed by "_output":

- "UDC06_45_Oven_output"
- "UDC06_45_Fridge_output".

In general, this must be done for every Excel file contained in that folder. If the folder contains 5 appliances, meaning 5 input Excel files, I should obtain 5 output Excel files... and so on.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following code only assing your path, in my case I have used a test folder path `path=r'D:\test`' this code will create a new folder  automatically in the same path.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from glob import glob

path=r'D:\test'  # add whatever your path is in place of 'D:\test'
input_folder='UDC06_45' # name of input folder
output_folder=input_folder+'_out' 

new_path=path+'/'+output_folder 


if not os.path.exists(new_path):
    os.makedirs(new_path)
    
files=glob(path+'/'+input_folder+'/'+'*.xlsx')

for file in files:
    name=file.split(path+'/'+input_folder+'\\')[-1].rsplit('.')[0]
    df=pd.read_excel(file)
    #do all your operations here
    df.to_excel(new_path+'/'+name+'_output.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Shuvashish, I had to fix a little problem inside my folder and now the code works perfectly!